# What are the inventories for minimalist approach?

Tags: linguistic-typology

I have questions regarding German phonology. my first question is the example required for minimalist approach.

According to Plank, the consonant phoneme counts for Standard German varies between 17 and 25 (items of contention are the affricates, the velar nasal, `/Z/`, `/Ã/`, `/h/`,
the glottal stop). The WALS value is “average” (22 ± 3).

Phonemic minimalists would prefer “moderately small” (15–18) – assuming the inventory maps
are about something like phonemes.

Now IPA has the inventories in accordance with the maximalist approach! Can someone provide the inventories for minimalist approach for these languages:

- Turkish
- German
- French

or at least one of them?

Comment: Try to make question titles that are informative about the main content of the question itself. For example, write something like: *“What are the minimal phonemic inventories necessary to describe Turkish, German and French?”* Also, try to write more carefully, with punctuation and paragraphs. Minimize discussion about yourself and your situation. Around here, there's no need to talk about your thesis, professor, or essay; it is enough to focus on the linguistic subject itself (and, with less stuff going on, the question becomes easier to read, which attracts more people to answer it).

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is "no", until you spell out the requirements of the "minimalist" approach that you have in mind. One problem dealing with major national and international languages is that they aren't uniform, especially French. West African French has fewer phonemes than Parisian French, for instance. A second problem is that you have to select an analytic standard for abstractness, since a more abstract analysis can reduce the number of phonemes. An example is the treatment of "r" in German, which is often not a phonetic rhotic, it's a vowel. A related issue is that you can eliminate phonemes by positing structure (for instance, vowel length and branching coda are in complementary distribution in Norwegian). Length, in particular, is a property that can be structurally analyzed (to eliminate phonemes) or featurally analyzed (long versus short vowels and consonants).

Additionally, contemporary theories of "minimalism" do not count letters, they at most count the defining features. That is, if only 9 features are needed to analyze an inventory under analysis A and 10 or 11 features are needed under analysis B, then A is more minimal and judged to be better. Generative analyses don't assign any value to counting phonemes, instead they assign value to not requiring rules and to not specifying underlying feature values (e.g. vowels are all voiced, so you don't have to specify vowels as being voiced). Government Phonology is one brand of fairly minimalist phonology, which exploits structure more and relies on "inventory" less: see Charette 1991 (*Conditions on phonological government*) and works by Wiebke Brockhaus and Markus Pöchtrager for German (the latter may have also written on Turkish).

If the goal is to lower the count of segments (which is the product of some arrangement of features – you're not interested in the composition of segments), you can take the [Standard German consonant inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology#Consonants) and chip away. You could eliminate [ŋ], as was classically done. All of the parenthesized segments can be eliminated since they are marginal or predictable. The affricates can be treated as clusters. Ich-laut and ach-laut can be reduced to one phoneme. Whether or not that give you a terrible analysis depends on your underlying theoretical axioms, so maybe saving three phonemes is a sufficiently large benefit that it compensates for the complexity it adds elsewhere (in stating the rules for syllable structure).